# Setting data value for each created element in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    for (var i = 33; i <= 127; i++) {

      var main = [];
      main.push(i);

      document.write('<div class="symbol"><a class="link" href="#" data-code="" data-placement="auto" data-toogle="tooltip" onclick="code()" title="' + String.fromCharCode.apply(this, main) + '">' + String.fromCharCode.apply(this, main) + '</a></div>');


       $('.link').each(function(){

          $(this).attr('data-code', i);

      });
    };

var code = function () {
    $('.input').value += String.fromCharCode($(this).attr('data-code'));
}
```

What i'm trying to do is a charmap. I can't figure out how to add its created unicode number, which is "i" here, to the data-code.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not use `Document.write`. Try creating HTML string and set it as innerHTML of an element. Also `$('.input')` this ill return an array and `.value` will throw an error. Check console

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem with adding it's data-code by

```
$('.link').each(function(index){
  $(this).attr("data-code", index+33);
});
```